# Google fit data via google python api libraries

Tags: python, google-fit

I'm using [this python library](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/fitness/v1/python/latest/fitness_v1.users.dataset.html) from google but I can't figure out what to use for the 'body' argument. Is there an example body that I can draw from to create the dict that this tool will need?

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
    workLaptop,
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read',
    redirect_uri='oauth:code:from:somehwere')

auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
webbrowser.open_new(auth_uri)

auth_code = "a;ldskjfa;lsdkfja;ldsfkja;lsdkfjaldgha;"

credentials = flow.step2_exchange(auth_code)
http_auth = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

service = discovery.build('fitness', 'v1',http_auth)
fitData = service.users().dataset().aggregate(userId='me',body=body).execute()
```

It's all fine until the part where I need to define the body. Here is the body that I'm trying:

```
body = {
    "aggregateBy": [
      {
        "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps",
        "dataTypeName": "com.google.step_count.delta" 
      },
    ],
    "bucketByActivitySegment": {
      "minDurationMillis": "A String", # Only activity segments of duration longer than this is used
    },
    "endTimeMillis": "1435269600000000000",
    "bucketBySession": {
      "minDurationMillis": "10", # Only sessions of duration longer than this is used
    },
    "bucketByActivityType": {
      "minDurationMillis": "10", # Only activity segments of duration longer than this is used
    },
    "startTimeMillis": "1435183200000000000", # required time range
    "bucketByTime": { # apparently oneof is not supported by reduced_nano_proto
      "durationMillis": "10",
    },
}
```

What is wrong with my body dict?  Here is the error code:
https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataset:aggregate?alt=json returned "Internal Error">

Here is an example of the object in the API explorer:
[image]

Comment: Here is the API explorer link: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/fitness/v1/fitness.users.dataset.aggregate?userId=me  It will allow you to 'craft' a body dict using the tool but I can't find a combination that will return values.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not 100% o fey with the Google API for the Google Fit, there definitely some issues with your JSON body request in the first instance.

For example:

```
    body = {
    "aggregateBy": [
      {
        "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps",
        "dataTypeName": "com.google.step_count.delta" 
      },
    ],
    "bucketByActivitySegment": {
      "minDurationMillis": "A String", # Only activity segments of duration longer than this is used
    },
    "endTimeMillis": "1435269600000000000",
    "bucketBySession": {
      "minDurationMillis": "10", # Only sessions of duration longer than this is used
    },
    "bucketByActivityType": {
      "minDurationMillis": "10", # Only activity segments of duration longer than this is used
    },
    "startTimeMillis": "1435183200000000000", # required time range
    "bucketByTime": { # apparently oneof is not supported by reduced_nano_proto
      "durationMillis": "10",
    },
}
```

Should actually be this;

```
    body = {
    "aggregateBy": [
      {
        "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps",
        "dataTypeName": "com.google.step_count.delta" 
      }
    ],
    "bucketByActivitySegment": {
      "minDurationMillis": "A String" # Only activity segments of duration longer than this is used
    },
    "endTimeMillis": "1435269600000000000",
    "bucketBySession": {
      "minDurationMillis": "10" # Only sessions of duration longer than this is used
    },
    "bucketByActivityType": {
      "minDurationMillis": "10" # Only activity segments of duration longer than this is used
    },
    "startTimeMillis": "1435183200000000000", # required time range
    "bucketByTime": { # apparently oneof is not supported by reduced_nano_proto
      "durationMillis": "10"
    }
}
```

JSON Based rest services are really unforgiving for the use of extra comma's where they should not be, it renders the string un-jsonable which will lead to a 500 failure.  Give that a try in the first instance ;)

Comment: doesn't seem to be that simple. Still got the 500 error. :(.

Comment: What I really need is an example configuration that works. I'm surprised google hasn't given this out somewhere.

Comment: `"minDurationMillis": "A String"` looks invalid

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert myself, but I have been playing with the API for a number of days. Here's a sample from my OAuth playground.

[Sample response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdBzp.png)

From what I understand, your "endTimeMillis": "1435269600000000000" is not properly defined as it's in nanoseconds. For it to be in milli, change it to "1435269600000"